# Entity metadata wrapper + entity reference + translation

Tags: 7, entities

I have two node types: 'festival', which can be translated and 'event', which untranslatable. Event has multivalued field reference to Festival, so that one Event referenced to all translated festival instances.
Now I need to load Festival title depending on current user language.

```
global $language;    
$fest_title = $emw_event->language($language->language)->field_fest_reference->value();
```

returns an array of all festivals ignoring language parameter.

How to get language-specific title?

Answer (score 0):

```
global $language;
$fests = $emw_event->field_fest_reference->value();
foreach ($fests as $fest) {
  if ($fest->language == $language->language) $fest_title = $fest->title;
}
```